# Find $N(t)$ at time $t$ when the limiting value is 50000.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

## Question

The number of people N(t) in a community who are exposed to a particular advertisement is governed by the logistic equation. Initially $N(0) = 500$ and it is observed that $N(1)=1000$. If it is predicted that the limiting number of people in the community who will see the advertisement is 50000, determine $N(t)$ at time $t$.

My assumptions: I will need $e^{-kt}$ at some point and also that when $t$ approaches infinity the remaining expression must simplify to 50000.

My solution:

$$
N(t) = \frac{25000000}{e^{-kt}+500}
$$

Does my solution seem correct? Was I a bit naive in blatantly assuming I will need $e^{-kt}$? I am still new to using euler's constant so I just threw it in there because the question stated that this is all governed by a logistic equation.

Comment: You will certainly "need $e^{-kt}$".  Your equation is not correct as it gives $N(0)=25000000/501\approx 49900$.  It looks like you are guessing, not understanding.  The [Logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) (does this match your definition? You didn't give yours) has three parameters and you have three pieces of data.  You should be able to find the parameters from solving three equations in three unknowns.

Comment: @RossMillikan how does one begin to define a modified Logistic Equation? I can't use the exact one in that Wikipedia link because if $50000$ is my limiting value and I use that in the numerator, then $N(0) = 50000$ which doesn't agree with the question.

Comment: Nothing "modified" is needed. The logistic function given in the WP page works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia gives the Logistic function as $N(t)=\frac L{1+e^{-k(t-t_0)}}$  As $t \to \infty$ the second term in the denominator goes to zero, so $L=50000$  Then we have $$\text {At }t=0\quad1+e^{kt_0}=100\\\text{At }t=1\quad 1+e^{kt_0-k}=50\\kt_0=\log(99)\\kt_0-k=\log(49)\\k=\log (99)-\log(49)$$